# Ranking MarkLogic search results

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying figure out a way to rank search results according to a field that is not part of the search criteria. i.e. relevance of the search not only depend on the matches but documents also have a default relevance rank among themselves.

My searches so far has failed and could not confirm if it is even a supported feature; most cts:search documentation is about ranking matches.

So, is there a built-in marklogic feature that allow us to assign a value multiplier to documents; based on element values for example.

thanks a lot,
K.

PS: I use marklogic 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `cts:boost-query`: it takes a primary query that has to match and a secondary query that just affects the score.

Comment: exactly what I have been looking for but could not find!, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the score based on the distance of a value in the document from a target value.  See:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_45452
```

You can also set the quality on the document to influence scoring.  See:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_68032
```

Hoping that helps.